# detect object through color in opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, color-picker, hsv

I am trying to detect my mobile by using hsv color range,but the problem is how i should pick color range to detect my mobile.

mobile color is metallic golden.

is there is any easy way to find color range in hsv if i know BGR value?

Here is my code

**detectMobile.py**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lowerColor = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    upperColor = np.array([74, 74, 83])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerColor, upperColor)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
   #cv2.imshow('res', res)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Please do not repost the same question. If you edit your post it will bump it to the front of the new queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy way : you can just write something similiar to this

```
lowerColor = np.uint8([[[0, 0, 0]]])
upperColor = np.uint8([[[74, 74, 83]]])
hsv_lower = cv2.cvtColor(lowerColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_upper = cv2.cvtColor(upperColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

as suggested in the opencv python tutorials ([1](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)) !

Comment: i followed opencv python tutorial, and i got hsv_color value [[[ 37 189 212]]] for BGR value of metallic golden color [55,212,175], now how i should adjust range?

Comment: Determine your range in the RGB colorspace and then convert it into hsv, just as the code I posted does.